# object information for pandas dataframe default to head()

Tags: python, configuration, pandas

With previous versions of PANDAS, upon typing the name of a dataframe and hitting enter, at an ipython prompt, the default output was dataframe.head() -- or some concise summary of the column names, number of non-null values / column, etc. as a list.

But now, in the most recent stable version (0.13?), the first 60 or so row are printed. Way to much information for me.

Is there a configuration file or setting I can access to revert back to the old behavior?

--thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#dataframe-repr-changes

Comment: Thanks Tom! Is there a way to default pandas to set_option('display.large_repr', 'info')? From what I can tell, this command doesn't persist between sessions.

Comment: If you're using IPython put that in your [config file](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/config/overview.html).